# почему такая низкая производительность у vector::operator[]

Tags: c++, массивы, vector, stl

суть, есть приложение, выглядящее, примерно, следующим образом:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
vector<bool> used;
bool func(int i) {
...код
        if ((used)[i])
            func(i+1);
...код
        }
    }
    return false;
}
int main()
{
    used.resize(100);
    func(0);
}
```

и в отчете профилировщика на вызов `used[i]` приходиться 50% всего времени работы программы, если `vector<bool> used` заменить на `bool [] used` время выполнения сокращается в 200 раз, и теперь на used приходиться 0.25%.

Также пробовал:

```
vector<bool> * used = new vector<bool>;  (*used)[i] - 50%
bool [] * used = new bool[100];          used[i] - 0.25%
```

проблема все так же остается и при:

```
int pp [100000];
vector<bool> used;
func(){
     int k;
     k = pp[90000];
     k = p[90000];
     func()
}
main {
     used.resize(n);
     func();
}
```

минимальный компилируемый пример

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int arr[1000000];
vector<int> arr2;
void func(int i)
{
    if (i < 1000)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 1000000; j++) {
            int k;
            k = arr[900000];
            k = arr2[900000];
        }
        func(i + 1);
    }
}
int main()
{
    arr2.resize(1000000, 100);
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = 100;
    }
    func(0);
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n"; 
}
```

arr - 0.1% времени
 
arr2 - 97% времени
параметры компилятора

```
/JMC /permissive- /Yu"pch.h" /GS /analyze- /W3 /Zc:wchar_t /ZI /Gm- /Od /sdl /Fd"Debug\vc141.pdb" /Zc:inline /fp:precise /D "WIN32" /D "_DEBUG" /D "_CONSOLE" /D "_UNICODE" /D "UNICODE" /errorReport:prompt /WX- /Zc:forScope /RTC1 /Gd /Oy- /MDd /FC /Fa"Debug\" /EHsc /nologo /Fo"Debug\" /Fp"Debug\test.pch" /diagnostics:classic
```

Comment: Для подобного вопроса совершенно необходим конкретный пример с конкретными результатами. Ну и убедитесь, что вы меряете программу, собранную в релиз варианте.

Comment: Это наверное режим Debug, в нём обычно проверяется не выходит ли индекс за пределы массива

Comment: Бинго! `/Od` - отсутствие оптимизации... Написали же, **убедитесь, что вы меряете программу, собранную в релиз варианте**

Comment: @VTT да, действительно, спасибо!

Answer (score 3):

Потому что [`vector<bool>`](https://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool) для экономии памяти хранит упакованные `bool` по 8 в байте, так что при обращении используется промежуточный прокси-класс, который эти байты распаковывает, выделяет нужный бит и возвращает (и, соответственно, упаковывает и записывает).

Так что это получается не просто обращение, а с кучей дополнительной работы.

Comment: при использовании других типов, проблема остается

Comment: На самом деле эта "куча дополнительной работы" может потенциально улучшить быстродействие. Однако в данном случае ничего сказать нельзя, так как ОП не привел ничего конкретного.

Comment: Хотелось бы посмотреть [минимальный компилируемый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), демонстрирующий реальную проблему с другими типами. Со всеми условиями - как скомпилирован, чем, с какими ключами...

Answer (score 2):

`std::vector` имеет специализацию для `bool`, которая оптимизирует используемую память. Условно, каждый элемент хранится как отдельный бит. Если такая оптимизация не требуется можно использовать хотя бы `vector<char>`, а ещё лучше ограничиться массивом постоянного размера, если есть такая возможность, т.е. использовать `std::array<bool>`, например.

`operator[]` вектора для типа `bool` возвращает объекты прокси класса, которые, вероятно, и отъедают существенную часть производительности.