# Убрать специализацию шаблона

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Навеяно вопросом о [`vector<bool>`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/952680/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%83-vectoroperator).

Итак, имеем шаблон класса, и некоторую(ые) специализацию(и). Допустим, что все это в коде, который мы не можем менять.

Есть ли возможность как-то **отменить** специализацию с тем, чтобы получить исходную функциональность для некоторого типа, для которого она переопределена специализацией?

Грубо - для того же `vector<bool>` отменить специализацию, чтобы он стал работать, как обычный `vector<unsigned char>`?

Comment: Мне кажется, что это чревато ситуацией с наличием *разных* определений (специализации шаблонного) класса в разных единицах трансляции, что грозит неопределенным поведением.

Comment: @VTT С этой точки зрения я не думал... А нет ли совсем обходного пути? Типа какого-то наследования?... Адаптера? Понятно, что можно наследовать от какого-то `vector<unsigned char>`, но имя-то `vector<bool>` использовать при этом будет нельзя...

Comment: Пожалуй ближайшей альтернативой будет использование некоторого класса-обертки для `bool`. [Ада-стайл `class my_bool_tag_t; using my_bool_t = strong_typedef<my_bool_tag_t, bool>;`](https://github.com/foonathan/type_safe/blob/master/include/type_safe/strong_typedef.hpp)

Comment: Создаете свой шаблон my_vector<bool> и в нем делаете что хотите. В том числе (например) наследуете его от vector<unsigned char>.

Comment: @pepsicoca1 Нет, это решение за рамками поставленной задачи. Тем более что шаблон при этом совершенно не нужен :)

Comment: Как вариант создать свой MyBool класс, определить все необходимые операции и подставлять его внутрить std::vector. По затратам явно дешевле в реализации, чем свой vector пилить для этой цели.

Comment: @ArtemLP Речь не о том, как решить задачу, а можно ли убрать специализацию.